# Preventing console window to close itself after returning value

Tags: c++

I'm c++ newbie. My first app looks like that.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int add (int x, int y);

int add (int x, int y){
return (x+y);
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int x, y;
    cin >>x>>y;
    cout <<add (x,y);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Got 2 questions:

1. Why console window closing itself directly after function returns value even if I used `cin.get();`?
2. I tested this application without `int add (int x, int y);` line at the top of file. It worked well. Do I need to write prototype for every function or application works without it too?

Comment: You only need to declare a function (write the prototype) if you plan to use it before it is defined. Since you're defining add before calling it in main, you don't need the declaration. But if you were to move the add function definition to after main, you would need the declaration at the beginning.

Comment: some IDEs are configurable to leave the console window open on program exit.

Comment: Of course if you run just the executable it won't. I always had that problem in my first year class because I couldn't figure out why it closed there but not in the IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question 1: The `cin >>x>>y` leaves a newline in the input buffer, which gets read by `cin.get` instead, causing it to go on.

Try

```
cin.sync(); //remove unread characters
cin.get(); //read one character (press enter)
```

Question 2: The prototype is there so you can let the compiler know the function exists, then use the function (say in main), and then define the body of the function later (say after main).

```
int add (int, int); //compile error if left out

int main()
{
    add (3, 4);
}

int add (int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: what if I use cin>>x; cin >> y;?Can you pls, explain the difference between this and mine code?

Comment: The `cin >> var;` reads what it needs to and stops. It's like if you say `cin >> x >> y;` and enter `5 4`. It will read 5 into x and 4 into y. In both cases, you press enter after your input is done, so it stops reading before the newline and it gets left in the buffer. `cin.sync()` clears anything in the buffer that is unread. On the other hand, `cin >> x >> y;` is identical to `cin >>x; cin >> y;`. `cin >> x` returns a reference to the `cin` object so that the other part (`>> y`) combines to form `cin >> y` because the `cin >> x` evaluates to just `cin`. This is called cascading.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `cin >> x >> y`, that statement only reads two numeric input values, but *not* the Enter keypress you need to enter the line. That Enter keypress stays in the input buffer and is consumed by `cin.get()` later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line to keep the console open instead:

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max());
```

Or if you're using Visual Studio you can run your program with ctrl+F5 and the console should remain open without these tricks. Or you could just run your program from a cmd.exe window you start yourself.

---

Function prototypes are only needed if you want to call the function before (or instead of) defining it in the current translation unit. This is why headers contain function prototypes for functions you define in another implementation file.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;



int main(void)
{


  cout<<" \nPress any key to continue\n";

  cin.get();

   return 0;
}
```